# WindowManager floating window through screen borders

Tags: java, android, floating, window-managers

I have a problem with floating window powered by windowmanager. It stops at screen border but i want it to go through.

```
void startF(int x, int y) {

    removePopup();

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    mainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    screenWidth  = displayMetrics.widthPixels ;

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mainActivity, new SingleTap());

    windowManager = (WindowManager) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mainActivity);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(mainActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams WMparams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(100,100,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

    //WMparams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.END;

    WMparams.x = x;
    WMparams.y = y;

    windowManager.addView(linearLayout, WMparams);
```

As in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following flag to the window: [FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

> Window flag: allow window to extend outside of the screen.

Comment: + it doesnt work with TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR but i changed it to TYPE_PHONE